# pg_rewind succeed but postgresql showing error when trying to make standby with common ancestor

Tags: postgresql

Have 3 node setup: node1(50.2), node2(50.3) and node3(50.4). node1(50.2) is primary and node2(50.3) and node3(50.4) are standby. I promoted node3 first and then node2 to make them independent. When i try to make the node3 slave of node2, using pg_rewind, it says below:

```
pg_rewind: connected to server
pg_rewind: source and target cluster are on the same timeline
pg_rewind: no rewind required
```

After this, when i start postgresql on the node3 in standby mode, i get below:

```
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15411]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  entering standby mode
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15411]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/2F164268
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15411]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  invalid record length at 0/2F164268: wanted 24, got 0
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15410]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  database system is ready to accept read-only connections
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL 14 database server.
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15415]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/2F000000 on timeline 2
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15415]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCFATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000002000000000000002F has already been removed
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15418]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCLOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/2F000000 on timeline 2
Dec 15 07:57:33 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15418]: 2022-12-15 07:57:33 UTCFATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000002000000000000002F has already been removed
Dec 15 07:57:38 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15465]: 2022-12-15 07:57:38 UTCLOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/2F000000 on timeline 2
Dec 15 07:57:38 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[15465]: 2022-12-15 07:57:38 UTCFATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000002000000000000002F has already been removed
Dec 15 07:57:43 fsrstandby.for.com postmaster[16087]: 2022-12-15 07:57:43 UTCLOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/2F000000 on timeline 2
```

There is no WAL archiving set. This is PostgreSQL 14. Does this means PostgreSQL pg_rewind can't be used when forming cluster between two independent primary having common ancestor?

Note: If i just promote node2 and run pg_rewind on node3 to join with node2, then it works correctly.

Comment: I don't think that `pg_rewind` can work in that scenario. You should not have promoted *both* standby servers.

Comment: Thats true, but we have operation called 'leave-cluster' which actually promote the node and make it read write. I did 'leave-cluster' on both node and then tried performing join-cluster between them. Why `pg_rewind` don't fail in this scenario? We look for `pg_rewind` return code and if it non-zero, we use `pg_basebackup`. But since, `pg_rewind` returned zero return code, it failed for us? What is best way to perform join-cluster between two promoted(leave-cluster) nodes? is it pg_basebackup only?

Comment: I think that `pg_basebackup` is the only option. I suggest that you change your procedure to only promote one standby. Otherwise you have a split brain, and data loss can ensue.

Comment: Ok but this is by design and we are aware on how to manage that data loss. We make new primary based on which node promoted last. Isn't there a way to detect that pg_rewind would not work and go for pg_basebackup? Here, problem is pg_rewind return success code as 0 and then PostgreSQL die saying WAL segment removed?

Comment: I would say that it is a bug that `pg_rewind` returns 0. It should not only check the time line number, but also compare the time the time line branched off. You may want to complain to the pgsql-hackers or pgsql-bugs mailing lists about that. Nonetheless, your procedure is wrong. You should identify which standby has the latest LSN received and promote that. Don't try to re-invent the wheel of a clusterware for PostgreSQL, it is a difficult wheel to invent. Use one of the existing solutions.

Comment: Ok thanks @LaurenzAlbe. Let me report this `pg_rewind` bug.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed with commit [009eeee74682](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=009eeee746825090ec7194321a3db4b298d6571e). If you upgrade to PostgreSQL v16 or better, it should work as you want. You could lobby for a backpatch to older versions by replying to [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/9f568c97-87fe-a716-bd39-65299b8a60f4%40iki.fi).

Comment: Is it possible to backpatch this to Postgres 14?

Comment: In the thread I linked, Heikki says that "the patch didn't apply cleanly 
to v13 and before", so I assume that v14 would be fairly painless. As I wrote, you'd have to write to a PostgreSQL mailing list (ideally pgsql-hackers) and express your wish there.